# Bootstrap 4 make the navbar-brand image overlap on big screen & shrink-to-fit on small screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Here's what I'm trying to do. I want to have the navbar-brand image overlapping the navbar without altering it's height (navbar has fixed height of 80px).
It kinda works, however I cannot get the image to fully expose, it's being cut at the top. I tried `vertical-align: top` but it just slightly changes the position, the image is still being cut off. I want it to start exactly at the top of the screen, without any padding.

On devices with screens smaller than `md` the overlapping image is being hidden and another one is show, which should now be `img-fluid` and adjust it's size to the size of the navbar. However when resizing the screen so the navbar collapses, the navbar size remains `80px` but the image starts overlapping it and the collapse-toggler button gets also messed up.
How can I get both of these things to work?

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYmMyg

Edit: Also, I noticed that setting the navbar to a fixed height actually prevents the collapse from working, because the height is limited. Is there any way I could increase the navbar height and keep the overlapping image and also keep the collapse working?

Answer (score 0):

```html
.navbar-brand {
  transform: translateY(calc(50% - 40px));
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

... will fix your problem (where `40px` is half the height of `.navbar`).
Working example: https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/pGLrOZ

The problem is rooted in `.navbar>.container { align-items: center;}`, which you don't want to mess with.

---

Ref: *"Edit"*, it's a different question altogether. Answering it here would be detrimental to anyone having a similar problem, as it decreases the chances of them finding the answer.
Avoid asking multiple questions at once. Your questions need to remain helpful for anyone with a similar problem, so you need to ask them separately.